# Why there is no ripple effect when I click on ListTile?

Tags: flutter, dart, ripple-effect

I have a `ListTile`. If I just write an empty `onTap` function it will show the ripple effect when I tap on it. But if I add the navigation function to the `onTap` function, it doesn't show the ripple effect when I tap on it. Why?

*Note that I'm using the [`go_router`](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) package for navigation.*

My code:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  …
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        …
        child: Card(
          …
          child: Padding(
            …
            child: Align(
              …
              child: Column(
                …
                children: [
                  …
                  ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
                      context.pushNamed(
                        AppRoute.editName.name,
                        pathParameters: {"userId": user.id},
                      );
                    },
                    title: const Text("Name"),
                    subtitle: Text(user.name),
                    trailing: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                  ),
                  …
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

I tried changing the position of `onTap` from `ListTile` to `InkWell`, but that didn't work:

```dart
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    context.pushNamed(
      AppRoute.editName.name,
      pathParameters: {"userId": user.id},
    );
  },
  child: ListTile(
    title: const Text("Name"),
    subtitle: Text(user.name),
    trailing: const Icon(Icons.edit),
  ),
),
```

I also tried wrapping the `ListTile` with a `Material`, but it didn't work either:

```dart
Material(
  child: ListTile(
    onTap: () {
      context.pushNamed(
        AppRoute.editName.name,
        pathParameters: {"userId": user.id},
      );
    },
    title: const Text("Name"),
    subtitle: Text(user.name),
    trailing: const Icon(Icons.edit),
  ),
),
```

Is there any working solution?

Comment: can be wrap with Ink, bt can you include a sample full widget from scaffold body,

Comment: Hi @YeasinSheikh I tried wrapping with Ink but it doesn't work. I also updated my question

Comment: even though `ListTile` on the bottom but idk why it is not working from current context, can you provide full of data on sample widget. dartPad will be the best.